# Too many wires coming out of ceiling fixture

Tags: wiring, repair, ceiling

Wiring in ceiling.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk2AP.jpg)I'm trying to replace my kitchen ceiling light fixture but... coming out of the ceiling I have 3 black wires, 3 white wires, a red wire and a ground! I didn't take a picture of how they were wired before removing old fixture - yes, I know. The new fixture only has a black, a white, and a ground.Please help!! Thanks

Comment: I assume that the question is "how do I connect the fixture?" We can't say. One of the black-white pairs could be a switch loop, but we can't know with what you've provided. You'll need to get your hands on a multimeter and do some investigation.

Comment: Did you only remove the wires going to the old fixture, or did you take them ALL apart?   If the latter, can you shoot photos of what's in the lamp box and also the switch box?  Don't unwire the switch also...

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

If your wiring is standard and NEC-compliant:

One cable is the feed, one is te line gouing to next lamp, the third (that has 4 wires: red, black, white and copper) is the wire from the switch.

Just connect whites together (the 4 from wall + one from the fixture), the blacks coming (from wall) together, and the black from the fixture to the red (from the switch)

If you're not sure / don't know how to check, hire an electrician to have it fixed